# Is it able to change the secondary receiver for delayed adaptive payment?

Tags: paypal

As title,

Is it able to change the secondary receiver? I am the primary receiver, i am intend to use delayed adaptive payment for my system, the thing is , before i want to release the payment, the secondary receiver might be happen doesn't complete the job i specified, another secondary receiver might completed the job, but i am intend to change the secondary receiver so the secondary receiver which doesn't complete the job cannot receive the money. Am i able to change the secondary receiver?

Answer (score 3):

Nope. It is not allowed to change it.
Within 90 days, you are able to release the money until all the receivers have performed some actions, the money will be credited to all the secondary receivers together.

Comment: Lets say, if there is any method, which can fulfil my requirement which is, delay payment, one to multiple receiver? Is it possible that, the money sent to primary receiver which the secondary receiver is still unknown, and i sent to secondary receiver once confirm the receiver? Is the pre approve payment able to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to change the secondary receiver email in [ExecutePaymentAPI](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/ExecutePayment_API_Operation/) as it takes only `payKey` as parameter.

The delayed chain payment expires after 90 days, if you fail to call the ExecutePayment API the transaction expires.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note from personal experience: If you try using Express Checkout and then MassPay, PayPal will not approve your business application because, and I quote, "They don't have visibility of initial payments". The only option is to use Chained Payments or Parallel Payments.

I had Express Checkout and Implicit Adaptive Payments set and my business application was denied. So I suggest you stick to using chained payments.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

Answer (score -1):

Once the secondary receiver is set in the PAY API, it is not possible to be changed later. To fulfill your requirement , I hereby suggest you firstly collecting the full funds from the payer, via PayPal's Adaptive Payment or Express Checkout. And then call MassPay API to send funds to your secondary receivers. Please refer to below page for more details about MassPay API.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/MassPay_API_Operation_NVP/

Please also be noted that MassPay is a feature that needs to be requested access to and approved. Please use below links to contact PayPal's Customer Service teams to request this feature.

http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_contact-general

http://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_contact-phone

Comment: will it be double charge? people sent to me, charge 4%, i mass pay another 4%? like this i got no profit from my website

Comment: if you able to answer me this one, i will claim this as answer